# Prepopulate jQuery datepicker with list of Django date objects

Tags: jquery, django, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

I have been stuck on this for a REALLY long time and I'm hoping someone can help because I really don't know that much about javascript. I'm using the multidatespickr found here: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/ It's just an adaptation of jQuery's normal datepicker. I have a list of Django date objects that I'm pulling from my database and I want to prepopulate the datepicker with those dates.

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //instantiate the calendar
    $('#main-calendar').multiDatesPicker({
        altField: '#id_dates_available',
        minDate: 0,
        addDates: [?????????]       
    });
</script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="custom-jquery-calendar">
     <div id="main-calendar"></div>
</div><!-- custom-jquery-calendar -->
```

And the Python dates list:

```
available_dates = hmod.Listing_Date.objects.filter(listing_id=listing.id)
```

I've been wondering if I can somehow use the addDates property and loop through my listing of available_dates in the javascript and add them one by one to the calendar??

Thanks for any help someone might be able to give. Let me know if I need to include additional information!

Answer (score 1):

If the JS part is found in your page it's as easy as:

```
addDate: {% for x in myDateList %} {{ x }} {% endfor %}
```

If not, you need to check if the library allows you to populate the list of dates using ajax, you'll need to create a view that returns `available_dates` as json.

Comment: Thank you for your help! @Ali